# how to add a new field into a document using painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

is there a way of creating a field in document within a painless script
if it does not exists?

i'm using something like:

```
     if(!ctx._source.tags.contains(....)
```

but tags field may not be exists at document

can it be done?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the `_update_by_query` API, I'd recommend you to do something like:

```
POST your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "tags"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.tags = ''"
  }
}
```

Otherwise, just using painless, you can do something like:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
      if(ctx._source.tags == null) {
        ctx._source.tags = null;
      }
    """
  }
}
```